# Why can't Apache start?

Tags: wamp

I'm setting up WAMP for the first time, and Apache won't start, and when I run the "Test Port 80" utility, it says that `Your port 80 is not actually used.`. From what I can tell, that means that something is blocking it from using Port 80.

I looked around several SO and blog solutions, and have never installed IIS (double-checked just in case).

Running Apache on port 81 worked, but I would really rather use Port 80.

`netstat -aon | findstr :80` gives me this vague list of IPs and ports and their status, but I don't know what to do with this information:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7808
  TCP    192.168.2.11:50860     141.101.114.59:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.2.11:50864     69.31.132.24:80        ESTABLISHED     688
  TCP    192.168.2.11:50875     134.170.119.140:80     ESTABLISHED     688
  TCP    192.168.2.11:50879     23.78.219.215:80       ESTABLISHED     688
  TCP    192.168.2.11:50880     23.78.219.215:80       ESTABLISHED     688
  TCP    192.168.2.11:50883     134.170.188.139:80     ESTABLISHED     688
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       7808
```

It also changes quite often.

`netstat -b` mentions a whole bunch of programs, but none using port 80. I left `netstat -b | findstr :80` running for a while and nothing popped up.

I went into Windows firewall and added rules that allow all traffic from port 80, so it's not that.

There must be a culprit on my machine taking up port 80 but I have no idea how to find it!

Comment: Do you run skype? In my experience that sneaky little program actually periodically uses port 80 and 443 to transfer data (this can be turned off in settings). There could be plenty of other programs who use port 80 occasionally, try turning all unnecessary programs off.

Comment: I'd rather use https://technet.microsoft.com/es-ar/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx to check which process is using port 80. Once on my dev machine, Skype was preventing wamp to start. Skype use port 80. Also check HTTPS port. If 443 is taken wamp won't start either.

Comment: @Engerlost that actually might be a great permanent solution! Thank you! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go.

I'd rather use technet.microsoft.com/es-ar/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx to check which process is using port 80. Once on my dev machine, Skype was preventing wamp to start. Skype use port 80. Also check HTTPS port. If 443 is taken wamp won't start either.